# IntStream irregular behavious dropping first element

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to find the median of three numbers using an IntStream and encountered irregular behavior.

So, here's my stream:

```
IntStream.of(first, second, third).limit(2).max().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

The idea is to get the middle by cutting off the highest value with limit, then getting the largest from those two. The method works in most cases, but the following case throws it off:

`first = 9 second = 8 third = 0`

The code works fine with this:

`first = 0 second = 8 third = 9`

This makes no sense, because according to IntStream#of

Returns a **sequential** ordered stream whose elements are the specified values.

The bug isn't fixed by adding a call to sequential before the limit. The behaviour is consistent on JDK 14 and JDK 8.

I first encountered it on repl.it.

Comment: Why do you leave the third element off with `limit(2)`? Your code is equivalent to `IntStream.of(first, second).max().ifPresent(System.out::println);`.

Comment: Oh, do you think `sequential` means `sorted`? It doesn't. You'll need to call `sorted()` for that. Sequential is the opposite of parallel.

Comment: Oh my god, I spent 30 minutes trying to figure out why sequential wasn't sorting it. I assumed it meant in sequential order (like 1, 2, 3).

Comment: Sequential order does not mean sorted order. It means one after another, as opposed to parallel where things may happen at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to make the stream sorted before calling limit.

```
IntStream.of(first, second, third).sorted().limit(2).max();
//                                 ^^^^^^^
```